# PySpark using Min function on timestamp selecting the wrong value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like so:

```
+-------+-------------------+
|id     |scandatetime       |
+-------+-------------------+
|1234567|2020-03-13 10:56:18|
|1234567|2020-03-12 17:09:48|
|1234567|2020-03-12 15:42:25|
|1234567|2020-03-09 16:30:22|
|1234567|2020-03-12 17:09:48|
|1234567|2020-03-09 16:30:22|
|1234567|2020-03-12 15:42:25|
+-------+-------------------+
```

And I would like to calculate the minimum and maximum timestamps for this id. To do so, I have used the following code:

```
dfScans = datasource1.toDF()
dfScans = dfScans.withColumn('scandatetime',f.unix_timestamp(f.col('scandatetime'), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))


dfDateAgg = dfScans.groupBy("id").agg(f.min('scandatetime').alias('FirstScanDate'),
    f.max('scandatetime').alias('LastScanDate'))
```

But I am getting the following return:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|id     |FirstScanDate      |LastScanDate       |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1234567|2020-03-13 10:56:18|2020-03-13 10:56:18|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Why is the min function not returning the right value?

Comment: are you sure you have same spark dependencies version for core and sql?

Comment: What is the data type of `scandatetime`?

Comment: I believe so, im running this in AWS Glue. spark version 2.4, python version 3, Glue version 1.0

Comment: `scandatetime` is initially a string but I have cast it to a timestamp. Code added to reflect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamps have hours in the 0-23 range, and thus you are using the wrong date format. You should be using `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` (capital `H`) ([See docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

The lowercase `h` refers to hours in the 1-12 range, and thus all values except `"2020-03-13 10:56:18"` become `null` upon conversion to `timestamp`.

```
from pyspark.sq import functions as f

dfScans = dfScans.withColumn(
    'scandatetime',
    f.unix_timestamp(
        f.col('scandatetime'), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    ).cast("timestamp")
)

dfScans.groupBy("id").agg(f.min('scandatetime').alias('FirstScanDate'),
    f.max('scandatetime').alias('LastScanDate')).show()

#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|     id|      FirstScanDate|       LastScanDate|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|1234567|2020-03-09 16:30:22|2020-03-13 10:56:18|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: sigh... always frustrating when it's an oversight like this. thank you!